# AWS S3 user policy strategy for client data storage

Tags: video, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I was wondering how to manage aws s3 access for my use case:

The user should be able to upload video files through my site directly to my S3 account. Later he should only see his own files in a video player.

How can I make sure that files are not accessible to anybody else? I know that I could use IAM roles, but I do not know if it is good practice or practical to create a new role for potentially thousands of users.

best regards, Chris

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that aws provides signed URLs or exactly this purpose.